# Python Permutation taken at a time

Tags: loops, python-3.x, recursion, permutation

I wrote nested loops to give me all posible permutations of all letter of alphabet taken 4 letters at a time.

```
def permutation():

    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

    perm = []

    for item1 in alphabet:
        for item2 in alphabet:
            for item3 in alphabet:
                for item4 in alphabet:
                    perm += [item1 + item2 + item3 + item4]

    return perm
```

So, when I do

```
permutation()
```

I get

```
['aaaa',
'aaab',
'aaac',
'aaad',
'aaae',
 ...
'zzzz']
```

Although this solves my particular problem (4 digit permutation), it's not an neat solution. Furthermore, if I'd like to make a n digit permutation (say, 10 digits), the nested loops would be a mess.

So, I was thinking I you can tell me how to implement this nested loops as some kind of function, using recursion or something of the sort.

By the way, I know that in this particular problem (4 digit permutation), I could use python libraries:

```
def permutation():

    from itertools import product
    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

    perm = [ ''.join(p) for p in list(product(list(alphabet),repeat = 4)) ]

    return perm
```

and this is what I would use in real life, but here I'm trying to figure out the algorithm of the permutation of letters of alphabet taken n letters at a time.

Comment: [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) has equivalent non-lib Python code. Is that what you want?

Comment: FYI, for speed/simplicity, you'd drop all the unnecessary `list`-ification in your `itertools.product` code.  You could just do `return list(map(''.join, product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=4)))`; the `list` calls you added around `alphabet` and `product` just forced pointless intermediate `list`s (particularly bad wrapping `product`, because those output `tuple`s could otherwise be stringified instantly and the peak memory usage would go way down).

Answer (score 0):

First, break this down into the two basic points of recursion: degenerate step (final condition) and recursion step.  Here, our final condition is to return the alphabet when we want strings of length 1.

For longer strings (length n), prepend each letter of the alphabet to all permutations of length n-1.

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def permutation(n):
    return [c for c in alphabet] if n == 1 \
        else [c + n_perm for c in alphabet for n_perm in permutation(n-1)]

print permutation(1)
print permutation(2)
```

Comment: You'd get much better performance if you looped over the recursive result first, then over the alphabet second (that is, reverse the order of your `for` loops in the second generator expression).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a N-digit permutation (say, 10 digits), I come up with two ways:

1)  Break up repeat 10 into 5+5 (or 3+3+4):

```
from itertools import product
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def permutation( * repeat):
        for p1 in product(list(alphabet),repeat = repeat[0]):        
            for p2 in product(list(alphabet),repeat = repeat[1]):  
                yield ''.join(p1 + p2) 

permutation(5, 5)
```

2) Simply choose repeat 10 like:

```
from itertools import product
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def permutation( repeat):
    for p in product(list(alphabet), repeat=repeat):
        yield ''.join(p)

for word in permutation (10): print word
```